# SASS mixin not taking variables

Tags: sass, mixins

I have following mixins in my SASS project:

```
@mixin define-size($height, $width) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}
@mixin define-square($size) {
  @include define-size($size, $size);
}
```

And I try to call them, but I get a compile error...
I've tried with:

```
@mixin define-square(45px);
@mixin define-square(45);
@mixin define-square("45px");
@mixin define-square("45");
```

And every time, I get the same error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...   @mixin define-square(": expected variable (e.g. $foo), was "45px);")
```

Other mixins in the same `_mixin.scss` are working correctly.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To call a mixin you use the `@include` directive, so instead of doing:

```
@mixin define-square(45px);
@mixin define-square(45);
@mixin define-square("45px");
@mixin define-square("45");
```

You should be doing:

```
@include define-square(45px);
@include define-square(45);
@include define-square("45px");
@include define-square("45");
```

See http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#including_a_mixin

---

Re: the error you're getting:

The SASS parser sees `@mixin define-square(` and assumes you're creating a new mixin, so it correctly expects an argument list, i.e. `($foo, $bar)`, but instead it gets `"45px"...` -- and so ends up giving you that error.